# Why can't I return a Vec<&str> from a function?

Tags: rust

I am trying to return a `Vec<&str>` but have been having issues converting `u64` to `&str` inside the while loop:

```
fn latest_ids<'a>(current_id: u64, latest_id: u64) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut ids: Vec<&str> = vec![];
    let mut start = current_id;
    while !(start >= latest_id) {
        start += 1;
        ids.push(start.to_string().as_str());
    }
    ids
}
```

> cannot return value referencing temporary value

If I return just a `Vec<String>` then it works fine.

```
fn latest_ids<'a>(current_id: u64, latest_id: u64) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut ids: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut start = current_id;
    while !(start >= latest_id) {
        start += 1;
        ids.push(start.to_string());
    }
    ids
}
```

The next function that is called after this requires a `&str` type parameter so should I be returning a `Vec<&str>` or just return a `Vec<String>` and let the caller handle the conversion?

Next function to be called after getting the result of `latest_ids()`:

```
pub fn add_queue(job: &Job, ids: Vec<&str>) -> Result<(), QueueError> {
    let meta_handler = MetaService {};

    match job.meta_type {
        MetaType::One => meta_handler.one().add_fetch_queue(ids).execute(),
        MetaType::Two => meta_handler.two().add_fetch_queue(ids).execute(),
        MetaType::Three => meta_handler.three().add_fetch_queue(ids).execute(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime you've introduced is saying "I am returning a vector of string references whose lifetime outlives this function". That isn't true, because you're creating a `String` then storing a reference to it. That reference will die at the end of the scope the `String` is created in.

To answer your question purely from a "design" POV:

> should I be returning a Vec<&str> or just return a Vec of String type and let the caller handle the conversion?

The method is called `latest_ids` .. and the ID's you're passing in are 64-bit integers. I think its acceptable given the name of the method that you should return 64-bit integers and the caller should do the conversion.

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let ids: Vec<String> = latest_ids(5, 10).iter().map(|n| n.to_string()).collect();
    let ids_as_string_references: Vec<&str> = ids.iter().map(|n| &**n).collect();

    println!("{:?}", ids_as_string_references);

    Ok(())
}

fn latest_ids(current_id: u64, latest_id: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut ids = vec![];
    let mut start = current_id;
    while !(start >= latest_id) {
        start += 1;
        ids.push(start);
    }
    ids
}
```

Prints: `["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]`

The double handling here is because you asked for references. Depending on further context around the code, the double handling might not be required. If you update your question with more information about the next function that requires a vector of `&str` references I can update my answer to help redesign it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I have updated the question with the next method being called.

Comment: How far down do these integral ID's get passed? It might be cleanest to pass a vector of integers all the way down until this vector is iterated over - then convert it to a `&str` as required in that loop.

Comment: It doesn't go down any more levels. I think add_queue should do the conversion, as meta_handler.one().add_fetch_queue(ids).execute() is used by other functions where the original ids are alphanumeric. What do you think?

Comment: I'll be honest - its a bit hard to give advice without seeing it as a whole. That said, my advice would just be to do the double-handling/conversions as far down the call stack as you can. If doing it inside `add_queue` is where you think it should sit then that sounds fine.